# How to Convert Int[][] to Double[][]?

Tags: c#, arrays, double, int

Guys, sorry for asking basic question,

i have a problem here where I have a `Int[][]` jagged array, and I want to convert it to `Double[][]` jagged array. Of course I don't want to change the value inside the array for example:

```
int[2][1] = 25
```

and when it converted to double,

```
int[2][1] = 25
```

still the same.

here's my code,

```
value = File.ReadLines(filename)
            .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(MyIntegerParse)
                .ToArray()
                )
            .ToArray();
```

So i have value[][] which is type is integer. and i want to convert it to double.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try to cast `(double)MyIntegerParse`

Comment: sorry, but put in where? in .Select(MyIntegerParse)?

Comment: `.Select((double)MyIntegerParse)`

Comment: it can't...any else suggestion?

Comment: @Stecya: Actually, he should use `.Select(x => (double)MyIntegerParse(x))`

Comment: @reza, is value defined as `int[][]` or as a `var`

Comment: @digEmAll : you are right. Should post it like answer

Comment: @Sweko: double[][] value = null; i declared like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
.Select(x => (double)MyIntegerParse(x))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
private double[][] intarraytodoublearray(int[][] val) 
        {
            var ret = new double[val.Length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < val.Length; i++ )
            {
                ret[i] = new double[val[i].Length];
                for (int j = 0; j < val[i].Length; j++) 
                {
                    ret[i][j] = (double)val[i][j];
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

something like this helperfunction might work